# Qt5.5 static build cannot find -IGL on ubuntu14

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, static

I have compiled qt 5.5 for static building and it works fine.

However, when I add the widgets "QT += widgets" in the pro file I get the link error "cannot find -IGL"

From what I read this is to do with the Open GL libs. I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

But no luck here... I am wondering if I need a static version of this? or maybe a symlink is missing, but I can't figure out the next step :(

**Edit** This is the actual error message:

> g++ -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-O1 -o ../targetRel/McpSupervisor main.o cconfig.o cconfigxml.o mcpprocessbase.o rpeprocess.o supervisor.o cipcomms.o mcpsupervisor_plugin_import.o moc_mcpprocessbase.o moc_supervisor.o moc_cipcomms.o   -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa -L/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib -lQt5Xml -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/plugins/bearer -lqconnmanbearer -lqgenericbearer -lqnmbearer -lQt5Network -L/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/plugins/platforms -lqxcb -L/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/plugins/xcbglintegrations -lqxcb-glx-integration -lxcb-glx -lQt5XcbQpa -lX11-xcb -lXi -lxcb-render-util -lxcb-render -lxcb -lxcb-image -lxcb-icccm -lxcb-sync -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-shm -lxcb-randr -lxcb-shape -lxcb-keysyms -lxcb-xkb -lQt5PlatformSupport -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lQt5DBus -lXrender -lXext -lX11 -L/usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/plugins/imageformats -lqdds -lqicns -lqico -lqjp2 -lqmng -lqtga -lqtiff -lqwbmp -lqwebp -lQt5Gui -lpng -lqtharfbuzzng -lQt5Core -lz -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lqtpcre -lm -ldl -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lrt -lGL -lpthread 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a(CrGlCur.o): In function `open_library':
>   (.text+0x33): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
>   /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/plugins/imageformats/libqjp2.a(jas_stream.o): In function`jas_stream_tmpfile':
>   jas_stream.c:(.text+0x7a4): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use`mkstemp'
>   /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/libQt5Core.a(qfilesystemengine_unix.o): In function `QFileSystemEngine::resolveGroupName(unsigned int)':
>   qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0x943): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function`g_get_user_database_entry':
>   (.text+0x25a): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
>   (.text+0xa3): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/libQt5Core.a(qfilesystemengine_unix.o): In function`QFileSystemEngine::resolveUserName(unsigned int)':
>   qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp:(.text+0x592): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   /usr/local/Qt-5.5.1/lib/libQt5Network.a(qhostinfo_unix.o): In function `QHostInfoAgent::fromName(QString const&)':
>   qhostinfo_unix.cpp:(.text+0x580): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [../targetRel/McpSupervisor] Error 1
>   09:49:17: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project qtMain (kit: Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit Static)
>   When executing step "Make"
>   09:49:17: Elapsed time: 00:08.

Comment: What's output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libGL*`?

Comment: The file libGL.so is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` ( Or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so` ... All 'mesa' packages : http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty-updates/mesa ... Static, libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev : Not available any more. The latast package was for Ubuntu 12.04 . ...

Comment: @KnudLarsen Does this mean that I won't be able to get it to work statically? - is there any work around?

Comment: Yes, you can rebuild mesa_10.1.3.orig.tar.gz  +  mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5.diff.gz  with the option ./configure  --enable-static  ,,, then you should get the static libraries . http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty-updates/mesa . The strange thing here is that the original OS = Debian has libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev for all versions : https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev .

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks, I guess the instructions to build are:
`./configure --enable-static`, 
`make`, 
`make install`
... sound about right?

Comment: @KnudLarsen also... have you any idea how to apply the patch? After unziping both I end up with folder Mesa-10.1.3 and file mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5.diff. I have tried `patch < mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5.diff`, this seemed to run, but could not resolve the names and asked for p[num] to be used... I tried all numbers (p0, p1, p2) no luck. Also loads of files where created at the same level as my diff file and Mesa-10.1.3 folder which leads me to think I don't really understand how to use this diff file : (

Comment: @KnudLarsen hmmm... this appears to be a can or worms, I was trying to configure the Mesa for building without the patch (until I figure out how to patch it). first run was: `./configure --enable-static` this seemed to get quite far, but then gave error: "cannot use static libraries for DRI drivers", then I tried `./configure --enable-static --disable-dri`, this gave the error: "LLVM is required to build gallium R300 on...", I looked these issues up, and seems I have to either install or re-build other libraries.... some even say it is an endless (not really) chain.... so I am a bit stuck : (

Comment: I probably should open a new thread entirely just for this...

Comment: Unfortunately like you many people are facing the same problem . And most of them dont have the answer. And you said that your project fails when you added `QT+= widgets` . Can you upload you .pro file ?

Comment: Oh ##$%$% man I got it ! . It was right under my nose but I didn.t see it :) . You my friend have a x32 system that is i386 system but you are installing packages for x64 systems. Thats why it doesnt work. I will update my answer  now :)

Comment: @SayanBhattacharjee Hey, err... yeah its 32-bit, I probably was not that clear on that one - I did try to write that in a comment but I just looked and I wrote "23-bit" ...oops :(
So... infact I am now away from my office until after Xmas so I can't test this ...ahhhhh... annoying, but I will try it out when I am back. I might be able to test it at home, but not on the target : ( I never knew you could do ":i386" for the install.... I assumed you got the correct one anyway?!

Answer (score 3):

**What is your actual problem :**

You have unmet dependencies .
You are thinking that you have all the required dependencies because you installed 
 `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

**The problem is that you have a i386 system that is x32 system. 

But you have installed development files for x64 systems using the commands above**

Here is the **ANSWER :**

Intsall the following things

```
   sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386  

   sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev:i386
```

Now it should work  **;)**

***Some other helpful stuff for visitors to this particular question***

**The lines below were my attempt to solve the problem but they did not work because the person who asked the question has a x32 system but the comments below work for x64 systems . But never the less the meta answer below will serve well for people who have the same problem and x64 systems. And also it will help problem to understand what are the basic steps to do after a similar problem occurs**  

@ code_fodder I wanted to ask a question by making a comment below your question but I do not have 50 reputations to do so.

So I have to use the answer submission form to do so. :(

Do you have Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities ?

If you dont have them then install using

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

If you want to use OpenGl ES then you have to install  Miscellaneous Mesa utilies (opengles, egl) using

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils-extra
```

Let me know if that works .

**POSTING NEW INFORMATION ON 17-DEC-2015**

I will post a portion of my project.pro file here . It specifically contains the library linking methods that I used for a simple OpenGL project.

I am using GLEW with OpenGL and SDL2

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           mesh.cpp \
           display.cpp \
           shader.cpp

HEADERS += \
         mesh.h \
         display.h\
         shader.h


unix|win32: LIBS += -lGL \
                    -lGLEW \
                     /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so
```

As you can notice I am using both static and dynamically linked libraries.

You may need to add:
  `unix | win32: LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/`  to your .pro file. However the path may be different for 32 bit systems. In that folder there are is the required mesa library files. These are the files for my system.

```
 zehel@zehel-PC:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa$ ls
 ld.so.conf  libGL.so  libGL.so.1  libGL.so.1.2.0
```

**Try compiling now and see if that works**

If that doesn't then either you have unmet dependencies or you are using old OpenGL.

Now after running the  `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`  you will be able to use a command called  `glxinfo`  . It will show you all required information about your graphics card.

Run  `glxinfo | grep "OpenGl version string"` 
It will show you what version of OpenGl and mesa you have
mine is like this 
 `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2`

If they are less than 3.0 then you are not using modern OpenGL and you may want to update your graphics drivers.

But if they are 3.0 or above then you are probably okay.

I cant reproduce your problem so I think that you have missing dependencies

See this posts on the QT forum where people with same problem as you are saying that there problems were fixed after installing the dependencies

http://forum.qt.io/topic/36282/solved-qt-5-2-0-and-lgl-issue

The last answer in the qt forum is quite good please refer it.

Update me whether it works or not .

Hope That helps .

Comment: Hey Sayan, no worries about making it an "answer", I have no problem with using common sense to get around petty rules :o
I will try this and if it works I will re-apply the bounty and send you the points. But from what I understand I thought I needed a static version of the mesa GL...? .. anyway, I will try this first as I have only run the two install lines in my post and not the ones you have specified :)

Comment: Truth be  told , I searched in google with your problem and most of them had their solution after they installed <code> sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev </code> I think that you have missing dependencies . I will update my answer / question above.

Comment: You may need to point the compiler towards the library directory. using `unix | win32: LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ ` . I updated my answer with that .

Comment: I tried all of these steps, I thought putting in the path for mesa libs might actually work, but none of them did :(
I have 23-bit Ubutnu, so my mesa is: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/` but I have the same files as you do. I installed all the extra libs from you, and from the other post (and from the building qt from git link within the post - which is where I derived my original setup from). But no luck. My mesa/GL version is `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2`. The actual output of my build, I will post as an edit into my question incase there is something more there...

Comment: I meant to say: `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa` not 64-bit

Comment: I saw your error message . It says you are building some app named McpSupervisor . And /usr/bin/make with code 2.

Comment: Did you install qtcreator by using `sudo apt-get install qtcreator` from the linux repository (file size was only 13 MB)? Or did you download from [link](http://www.qt.io/download/) ?. where the file size are 600 MB to 1 GB. Last year I installed qtcreator on windows 7 using the download link and like you nothing compiled .

Comment: Yes, I installed Qt Creator from the website, but then I had to download the Qt source from git repo and re-compile it statically so I can compile statically. So my entire build is static (including linkage), so I think the issue is there are no openGL static libs (*.a instead of *.so)
Another thing I found (recently) is that the openGL libs are not meant to be statically linked because they are interfacing with the graphics card directly and should be dynamically linked on the target... so leaves me wandering if I am following the correct route here at all :o

Comment: So, I tried the ":i386" post fix for the mesa drivers, but I already had them installed. I think (at least for some drivers) the correct version is selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the path where the GL library can be found, for exmaple by using the -L option to GCC, which has the following man page description:

> **-L***dir*
>   Add directory *dir* to the list of directories to be searched for **-l**.

Comment: Hi hkBst, I believe that they are already in my path or something?, but it's worth a shot :o - again if this works I will re-apply the bounty and award it :)